# Remove or Convert &#39; to (')

Tags: c#, html, .net, ascii

I am consuming an api and I noticed that it comes back with `"&#39;s"` and not an apostrophe. Since I am not going to be displaying this text in html this will make my text look weird when I display to the user.

How can I remove or convert(preferred)? I don't know if this api I am working with will be sending any more of these special codes so I don't know if I can just simply do a replace.

Answer (score 20):

As of .NET 4.0 you can use [`System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) (resides in the `System.Web.dll` assembly, in the namespace `System.Web`).

**Or** you could use the [`System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388354.aspx) function, you don't even need an extra reference for this (because it resides in the `System.dll` assembly, in the namespace `System.Net`).

Usage:

```
string myStringToDecode = "Hello &#39;World&#39;";

string decodedString = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myStringToDecode);
// or
string decodedString = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(myStringToDecode);
```

Comment: Ya this crossed my mind but I was not sure what will happen with script tags and bad stuff like that. I hope the api I use takes care of those bad things but the last thing I would want to do is make those active again(though since it is an app should not be a problem but if I would all of sudden display them on a webpage)

Comment: It wil decode all HTML entities (that are supported). You can do some tests yourself easily I guess. However, just make sure your application handles that well, and there should be no problem?

Answer (score 0):

The [MatchEveluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) is available since .NET 1.0 and comes in handy if you want to address this problem in a more generic fashion - i.e. do more than just [HTML character decoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#HTML_character_references). The general recipe looks like this:

```
MatchEvaluator ev = (Match m) => Char.ToString((char)Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value));
string result = Regex.Replace("The king&#39;s key.";, @"&#(\d+);", ev);
```

Comment: Only to be replaced with the overhead of data type conversions and regex :)

Comment: Fair enough. I found another good reason to know about the MatchEvaluator :)

Answer (score -1):

Why aren't you uysing [String.Replace Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) for this purpose. Just find your string and replace it with your required one.

```
string myStringToDecode = "Hello &#39;World&#39;";
myStringToDecode.Replace("&#39;","'");
```

Comment: I mentioned in my post, I don't know how many of these character encoding this api has. I don't want to make a gigantic list of replaces.